# Energy conservation of oscillating electric field interacting with charged particles

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, charge, maxwell-equations

Consider a charged particle at rest in a vacuum. A traveling oscillating electric field reaches the particle, making it oscillate as well. The particle has gained kinetic energy with that interaction, so by energy conservation, the field must have lost the energy that the particle gained, right?

My question is: how does the electric field lose energy in that interaction? My guess is that the charge, by accelerating, creates an electric field that interferes destructively with the first one, so that the amplitude of the total electric field decreases, thus reducing the energy stored. However, I don't know if that's right and I don't know how to evaluate the electric field produced by this accelerated charge.

Answer (score 1):

> so by energy conservation, the field must have lost the energy that the particle gained, right?

Usually in macroscopic EM theory, energy is assigned to a region of space, and described as energy of the field, via the Poynting formulae, which makes energy density a function of total fields $\mathbf E,\mathbf B$ only. This is appropriate when the particle charge is distributed with finite density in space, and thus has non-zero dimensions. For example, a small ball of charge.

When such ball of charge accelerates, it produces its own time-dependent EM fields, and these act back on the particle with EM forces, while net force due to this is not zero (Newton's 3rd law does not apply). This effect is called electromagnetic self-force. The result is the particle gets deformed and has somewhat lower acceleration than the one you would get from a simple application of the Lorentz formula with external field. It is possible to describe this as a result of self-induction, or additional electromagnetic mass.

Now, it is not clear how to calculate kinetic energy of the particle. If we calculate it using the bare mass with no electromagnetic mass contribution, then local energy conservation will hold. Increase of kinetic energy(with no EM mass contribution) and EM energy inside the particle  will equal total influx of EM energy from all directions around the particle. However, any simple region that contains the particle (including the EM energy inside the particle) does not have to lose energy, because energy comes from the outside of the region (remember, there is the travelling wave coming from distance).

If we used total effective mass (including the EM mass), the law of local conservation of energy would not be so obviously holding, unless we doctored the definition of the field energy in just the right way to add the effect of the increased mass; since kinetic energy change is greater, the field energy change has to be greater as well, and this is possible only for different definition of the field energy.

In practice it is hard to determine how much, if any, mass of elementary particles is electromagnetic. So it is not clear which definition of field energy should be used when checking local conservation around the elementary particle. Independently of this, it is hard to verify conservation of energy of EM wave + electron in experiment. We believe in local conservation of energy because it is a nice idea that has nice consequences, and our best equations for EM field and the particle obey it. These equations are valid in many situations in which we have checked, but nobody is measuring field at $1000^3$ points of space around the particle and checking whether the Poynting energy definition or some other definition of field energy obeys the law of local conservation.

> how does the electric field lose energy in that interaction?

Not just electric field; a travelling oscillating EM field has magnetic component as well, and in simple cases (plane wave, spherical wave) carries just as much energy as the electric one. So (if we have a big region with the source of the EM wave inside), it is electromagnetic field in the whole space around the particle that loses energy, while kinetic energy of the test particle increases.

> the charge, by accelerating, creates an electric field that interferes destructively with the first one, so that the amplitude of the total electric field decreases, thus reducing the energy stored.

That's the right broad idea, just don't forget that when the particle has already non-zero velocity, the same process goes on for magnetic field as well. Also, the interference is destructive in only some directions and regions of space, in others it may be constructive.

Comment: In laboratory experiments we see that energy is conserved. Accounting for this mathematically in the microscopic interaction is a tricky business.

Comment: When two wave traveling in the +x and -x directions collide and interfere destructively, is it your view the energy of the system goes to zero?

Comment: @Daniel what system? Interference of EM waves is compatible with local conservation of energy. In some place energy density goes down, in other it goes up.

Comment: @JánLalinský where would it go up once the waves overlap?

Comment: I mean let's say the wave is 100 units of energy, the particle scatters 10 units of which in a non-interfering direction. The amplitude of the wave has to be 90. To achieve 90, the particle would have to scatter another 10 units in the interfering direction. Thus from 100 units originally, we have 120 now (100 original wave, 10 to reduce its amplitude to 90, and another 10 in a different direction not interfering the original wave). If I'm incorrect, I'd definitely appreciate finding out how the energy balances despite an appearance to the contrary...

Comment: But due to the discrepancy, I believe that destructive interference is a secondary effect, and the wave somehow transfers energy to the particle "right away" upon doing work on it. So when the particle scatters 10 units, it gets those from the wave, and the wave goes down to amplitude 90, before and independently of any subsequent interference. If that's no correct, I'd be glad to find out the correct answer...

Comment: @Daniel Not sure what exactly you mean by overlap, but two equally strong  waves of same wavelength moving in opposite directions never add up to zero in the whole space. Instead, so-called standing wave is the result - this is an oscillation with a wave pattern that changes in time, but does not move in any direction. Energy moves around but is conserved locally.

Comment: What seems to sum up to zero in some cases of interference is the visible part of the wave - in case of surface waves on water, the boundary between the water and the air can become flat. But even if this happens at some instant, the water surface is moving at that instant, and energy of the wave is stored in kinetic energy of the flat surface. In a while, the surface wave reappears, as some kinetic energy transforms into potential energy. Similarly with EM waves - two waves can add up to have zero electric energy, but if that is the case, all the energy is magnetic.

Comment: I was thinking of two short pulses overlapping in space. But even for the scenario described, let's say the wave hits a "wall" bounces back elastically, and ultimately produces a standing wave pattern. I would say that integral of the standing wave's amplitude at a given moment is not proportional to the amount of energy contained in the wave - the energy would be relate to the integral of amplitude over dLength of forward traveling part of the standing, summed with a second integral of the amplitude*dLength of backward traveling part of the wave (in absolute values). That's my view anyhow...

Comment: I agree with your last comment. I didn't see as I was typing mine. Exactly, so if energy is preserved "unseen", and destructive interference may not be a good candidate to explain the energy loss mechanism of the original wave (back to the OP question).

Comment: Such two pulses of EM waves can never add up completely destructively. Even if electric fields add up to zero, magnetic fields won't add up to zero.

Comment: That's correct, energy of mechanical wave depends not only on the pattern of displacement, but also on velocities. In EM waves, energy depends on electric and magnetic field.

Comment: I agree with the last 2 comments, but my inference then is that destructive interference is not why the original wave loses energy (back to the OP question). (I did +1 on the comments I fully agreed with).

Comment: @Daniel EM energy in the vicinity of the charged particle decreases, it is a function of total electric and magnetic field, and superposition of the primary and secondary EM field does happen there, so the energy change and two fields interference are related. However, the secondary field looks nothing like the primary field, and it is not really a wave -  it is centered in the particle and it is not a wave, so you can't transplant results on interference of two free waves to interference of a wave and strong field attached to a charged particle.

Answer (score 0):

Without proof: unless radiation is emitted the acceleration is transient and the charge is at rest again after the travelling wave has passed.

Comment: Well radiation would be emitted, since the charged particle is accelerated. Also, the charged particle will be at rest at the end only for certain special waveforms, not in general.

Comment: @JánLalinský I neglected Compton scattering which will change the wavelength at most by 4.8 fm in the case of backscattering.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering

Comment: @JánLalinský Could you provide an example of such a waveform?

Comment: It depends on internal structure of the particle. In the simplest case of point particle with no self-interaction, a symmetric oscillation that starts and ends at zero will do, like one period of a sine wave. For composite particle such symmetric wave packet probably won't do, because self-force comes into play; the wave packet has to be changed asymmetrically to make the particle stop moving.

Comment: @janlalinsky The particle could be a satellite that is destroyed by a laser weapon. Indeed.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not very qualified to answer this question, but I believe I contribute: despite the appeal of the suggested idea - the radiation from the acceleration of the particle, interferes destructively just right with the original wave so as to reduce its amplitude just by the amount of work done on the particle - I believe it's not how it works.

The idea even contradicts itself in a way: the particle was accelerated, and then releases the energy given to it through radiation.

Starting from the fact that amplitude of the original wave already contains the sum total of energy, if after the destructive interference the original wave has less amplitude, where is the energy transferred to the particle? It's used for destructive interference. Thus in the end state you have the energy given to the particle "missing" from the system, because you dedicate it for destructive interference.

Perhaps you can save the idea by saying that beside the destructive interference there is radiation from the particle in a different direction such that the original radiating energy equals the final radiating energy.

But I believe it's not the case that the reason the amplitude goes down is by a process of permanent destructive interference in the same direction as the original wave forever.

Here's how I believe it works:

Whenever the original wave transfers energy, the amplitude goes down nearly "right away" as the wave does work on the particle. I'm not sure what is the mechanism for this, though.

After the energy transfer, and the reduction of the original wave's amplitude, the particle radiates all the energy given to it, with the total redistributed radiation equalling the original.

---

But there is a more important point still to contradict the OP proposed mechanism - while destructive interference cancels two energy components, it doesn't eliminate their existence. Thus if there is a wave with amplitude zero, but it's made of two destructively interfering waves, the system's energy is not zero, but related to energies of the constituent waves. This places further requirements to achieve the right energy balance under the mechanism of destructive interference.

If the original wave goes through destructive interference just right to eliminate the energy it spent on the particle, the absolute value sum of the positive and negative amplitude components equals to the original amplitude.

If both components sum in absolute value to the original energy, you can't have additional radiation in a different direction as that would mean that the total post interaction energy is now greater than the original.

(At the beginning of the answer, I went along with the view that destructive interference eliminates the energy when the amplitude is decreased to show that even under that view, the proposed mechanism doesn't fully work. But this paragraph is based on what I believe is the right approach, namely not taking interference as actually eliminating the energy, even if the result is that the amplitude is cancelled.)

Comment: Two intfering wave don't eliminate energy as otherwise energy conservation would be in big trouble. Two interfering waves before running over each other would have energy, but when they run over each other the system has zero energy? No, even as the net work the interference pattern does is zero.

Comment: Also, even if the interaction with the particle is such that one time the wave does work on the particle, and half a period later the particle does work on the wave's E field, and only a minor amount of the energy is radiating in the process, it's still less the case that the change in the amplitude of the original wave through the process are in consequence of destructive interference. No doubt destructive interference is present, but it's not exact to reduce the amplitude of the original wave just right. And even if it did that, we saw that interference doesn't figure in the energy balance.